Ants infested house
We never had a ant in our home ever but since last month I seen so many ants, I took some advice from other post and used baking soda which stopped them for weeks but now again they have showed up but I do not know where are they coming from, it is every type, with small feathers, big and small. We live in a story house, today I saw few on stairs and around the house.
The area where they were coming out of is still covered with baking soda and no sign of ants there but this time I cannot figure out where are they coming from. I got kids and I really want a solution. What should I do. I live in North west of england.
Edit: I sprayed my stairs with baking soda overnight but I don’t think it made any change as I can see some ants in my room today.

Why soda? You want to keep the ants alive? If not, see here for solutions.

There are many types of ants. You might find it useful to know what is attracting them. For example some ants like sweets, some are attracted to fats -- and carpenter ants eat wood. Have you put down bark chips? Noticed sawdust accumulating?

So they are not coming up the stairs. In my apartment, there is a soil & vent pipe in the kitchen which goes through the concrete floor, but the hole is not sealed. I know this because I get kitchen smells from another apartment, and there are no other adjoining kitchens. Also electricity and water come in via shared ducting too.
I recommend using a bait that the ants carry back to the nest and poison the colony. There are several commercially available formulas.
Place it near where they can come in, so that they don't have to roam the flat. If they are coming under the door, place it in the stairs area so they don't want to enter the flat.
Don't place it anywhere the children or pets can access. For example under an upturned bucket stood on a few tiles, with a weight like a brick on the top. And behind the plinth under the kitchen units.

Yes you absolutely have to get something that will kill the colony which is outside. I’d recommend a professional at this rate.

For insects that tend to crawl/walk I recommend several different solutions.
1 . Because insects are rather resistant to most chemicals diatomaceous earth is similar to dust on the moon vs a spacesuit. Insects that cannot walk without being torn apart tend to not continue to walk that way. Put this on the outside of where you see them entering from (if at ground level of course)
2 . Borax! The safe chemical that attacks the outside of insects (it dries them out) but is harmless to you. I literally won a battle vs cockroaches using this stuff, I sprinkled it along all the dark corners and edges.
3 . Bait based methods as others mentioned. Borax is a common insect poison for ants in these traps as well. It messes up their digestion and takes about 1-2 days to kill them, so it always ends up getting back to the nest.
For a temporary solution, windex and general cleaners will kill a lot of insects as well...
Peace be with you, and good luck with the ants.

Apparently I need to expand on why these things work. So here I go. As requested by a bot I assume. Here are some links...
For information regarding Diatomaceous Earth please review the National pesticide information center.
For information regarding Borax please review the National pesticide information center.
For information regarding bait based traps for ants please review the National pesticide information center document regarding hydramethylnon. ( a very common chemical used within bait type poisons.)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

With all due respect in what way is my answer unclear?

Because somebody reviewed it as such. If it's detailed enough, feel free to just flag that kind of comment for removal. One thing I would fix though is your use of quotes. When you use the > character, that's for quoting. For lists, please use list formatting (-).

One probable reason for an unclear flag is that your answer contains more than one suggestion.  Answer posts should contain one answer so that voting and acceptance are clear.

So it would be more desirable for me to post 3 answers instead of a concise post with 3 methods that are effective?

This is not a permanent solution or the best one (if it's really bad use the bait that they carry back to their nests), but when I get ants I get an all-purpose cleaner and spray it all over the place they're coming from.  It kills them instantly.  Then I don't wipe it whatsoever (it is kind of gross looking but this should be relatively temporary).  If you don't know where they're coming from, just follow the trail, spraying them everywhere you see them, eventually you will find their entrance.
I believe the combination of the wet floor (they don't like being wet) + the all-purpose cleaner that is toxic to them + the smell of a bunch of dead ants both deters them and creates a barrier so they physically can't enter without walking through the toxic all-purpose cleaner.
I have to repeat this every morning or multiple times a day but it usually stops them after less than a week.
Also, make sure you have no food out, vacuum and sweep well to get rid of crumbs.  If some come in and find no food they will have no reason to keep coming, especially if a bunch of them die every time they enter.

Here is an idea if you want to avoid killing them. Place some sugar or honey on a piece of paper on the floor, in an area visited by ants. Give them time to discover it and to organize themselves to get it to their colony. Once you see the trail clearly, move the dessert very close to the "access point" - some hole of some kind. If it is the area of tubes and cables, you probably need to find the beginning of that - towards the colony - it might be difficult or impossible. Wipe the ants back in the hole. Cover the hole. Problem solved. Repeat if there are several access holes.
